# Why do all my DocuSign calls return "Invalid UserId."?

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Here is my program.cs

```
using DocuSign.eSign.Api;
using DocuSign.eSign.Client;
using DocuSign.eSign.Model;

var docusignClient = new DocuSignClient();
DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.OAuthToken accessToken = docusignClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
    "client id",
    "userid",
    "account.docusign.com",
    System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("privateKey.txt"),
    expiresInHours: 1,
    new List<string> { "signature", "impersonation" }
    );

// I can successfully get my user info and it looks correct.
DocuSign.eSign.Client.Auth.OAuth.UserInfo userInfo = docusignClient.GetUserInfo(accessToken.access_token);

var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(docusignClient);
EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(
    userInfo.Accounts[0].AccountId,
    new DocuSign.eSign.Model.EnvelopeDefinition
    {
        // Does not matter what I put in here,
        // the response is always "Invalid UserId."
    }
    );
```

and here is my csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocuSign.eSign.dll" Version="6.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I have also tried getting an envelope by id and listing brands. Any endpoint I call returns "Invalid UserId.".

I think the DocuSign Api hates something that it sees in my jwt (which it generated). I've tried with different user ids and different account ids. The response is always "Invalid UserId.".

Comment: So you can get the user info? What's the problem then? This is a little unclear. Could you please edit your question to be more clear and specific?

Comment: your code has ""userid" where it should have the userId, how do you actually obtain a valid userId? what do you really do in your code? If you put this string, then yes, it's invalid userId, every time

Comment: I also highly recommend you download a C# quickstart, you can pick JWT, and that will set up everything for you, so you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: You need to get the REST API's URL from the Account returned by the call to UserInfo, and this is the URL you have to call for all calls after you authenticate. The Auth API uses a different URL's than the REST API. If this is the Demo API you can get away with hard coding the Demo REST API URL for testing and development, _but_ once you start calling the Production DocuSign API's you have to use the URL returned with the Account when you authenticate.

Comment: The "client id" and "userid" are just pseudocode (because I can't paste the actual ids here in SO). My actual code has real ids for arguments.

Comment: Also, you aren't putting the token in the request header but it's required. Once you authenticate and get the token, you have to add the token to the request header for all REST API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get our Access Token and the user's Account

```
string clientId = "**your-client-id**";
string userId = "**your-user-id**";
// demo site auth url: account-d.docusign.com
// prod site auth url: account.docusign.com
string oAuthBasePath = "account-d.docusign.com";                             
DocuSignClient authClient = new DocuSignClient();

var accessToken = authClient.RequestJWTUserToken(
     clientId,
     userId, 
     oAuthBasePath,
     System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("privateKey.txt"),
     expiresInHours: 1,
     new List<string> { "signature", "impersonation" });

// Use received access token to get user info and account            
var userInfo = authClient.GetUserInfo(accessToken.access_token);
var account = userInfo.Accounts.FirstOrDefault();
```

We now have everything we need and can make calls to the REST API...

```
// set the account's rest api url using the account info previously received
string accountRestApiUrl = $"{account.BaseUri}/restapi";           

// I perfer to create a new client for all rest calls, if your application gets
// complicated then isolating the auth calls from the rest calls may be useful
DocuSignClient apiClient = new DocuSignClient(accountRestApiUrl);

// We add the auth token to the request header for this client,
// this must be added to all rest api calls
apiClient.Configuration
      .DefaultHeader.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken.access_token}");

// make rest api call
var envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
var envelopeSummary = await envelopesApi.CreateEnvelopeAsync(account.AccountId, 
     new DocuSign.eSign.Model.EnvelopeDefinition
     {
         // envelope definition
     });
```